# How do you create a layout that is as shown in the image?

Tags: android

[image: Required image]

I am off to creating a travel app which had such a design as in the pic above. The central dot denotes intermediate stops between 2 locations. The first is source, the second is destination.

I would like to know the best way to acheive the layout as described in this image for a travel app.

Thanks in advance.

Code I tried below is here: (Sample)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="224dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_go_search_api_holo_light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_go_search_api_holo_light" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF00" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can get source, intermediate, times in the layout, but not sure how to add the dynamic intermediate 'dots' in the layout. Also please note that there can be multiple intermediate stops.

Comment: Use 9 patches as backgrounds

Comment: But would this be suitable for a dynamic intermediate locations? if there are multiple of them?

Comment: Create one vertical line and give left drawable attribute to each `textview ` in the xml layout.

Comment: @AbhilashLR Yes, just that in the ListView adapter you must decide which of the three 9 patches assign to the image

Comment: @dergolem.. Not sure if the 9 patch will still be able to create intermediate dots. If u have a code piece, maybe I can try that out as well.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @preeti.. Am trying as archi mentioned. I guess u stated the same. If not pls suggest ur way

Comment: `as archi mentioned.` which is no more no lesss of what I told you (just that I'm using 9 patches, because of stretching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said these locations will be dynamically populated and count might possibly be high, you can try a **ListView, with divider height as 0** and items as the following:

**Source: 1st item**

[image]

**Other intermediate locations**

[image]

**Destination: last item**

[image]

ListView would have these:

```
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:divider="@null"
```

Comment: Wow! I never thought of such an implementation. Let me work this out n if it solves the issue, guess it should, shall nark as right answer

Answer (score 1):

Inside a `LinearLayout` with `orientation = horizontal` keep one `ImagView` then `TextView` and then another `TextView`

Comment: You can **get rid of the ImageView** and use a **compound drawable**, instead, so to optimize performances.

Comment: Give it a try, you might be pleased by the results - especially with a ListView containing many items.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView ... />
    <TableLayout>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView ... /> <!-- Source -->
            <TextView ... /> <!-- 9:30 -->
        </TableRow>        

        <TableRow>
            <TextView ... /> <!-- Intermediate -->
            <TextView ... /> <!-- 9:30 -->
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView ... /> <!-- Destination -->
            <TextView ... /> <!-- 9:30 -->
        </TableRow>        

    </TableLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is table layout recommended for such scenarios?

Comment: @AbhilashLR If your activity's layout is simple and light weight, table layout does not affect your performance

Comment: But this isn't a simple layout. There are dynamic data views that are in place. The intermediate locations is in itself dynamic numbers.